# How to horizontally flip Highchart's chart?

Tags: highcharts, flip

[Here](http://goo.gl/6x8v93) is the chart I'm using.

How do I change the chart to go low to high? Basically just horizontally flip it. The values need to be changed to go from low to high, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip it by [reversed](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed) axis parameter.

```
 xAxis: {
            reversed:true,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4hML/6/